# Strange final line in table

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm trying to put that line white like the others, but I don´t know why it is different.
Does anyone know how can I put it ok?
I'm using datatables "plugin" to make this.

[image]

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example1').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<main align="center">
  <br>
  <br>
  <h2 class="teste">Lista de Utentes</h2>
  <?php $urgencias = DBRead5()?>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:70%">
      <thead>
        <th align=center>Utente</th>
        <th align=center>Telefone</th>
        <th align=center>Seguro</th>
        <th align=center>ID de Utente</th>
        <th align=center>Editar</th>
      </thead>
      <?php
            foreach( $urgencias as $cl )
            {?>
        <tr>
          <td align=center>
            <?php echo ($cl['nome']) ?>
          </td>
          <td align=center>
            <?php echo ($cl['telefone']) ?>
          </td>
          <td align=center>
            <?php echo ($cl['seguro']) ?>
          </td>
          <td align=center>
            <?php echo ($cl['idutente']) ?>
          </td>
          <td><a href="alterar.php?id=<?=$cl['idutente']?>">&#9998;</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="criar_urgencia" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Criar utente</button>

  </div>
  <br>
</main>
```

Comment: You sure the `html` markup is like this one? If yes, you are missing the `<tbody>` opening tag.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML please, not the PHP. It's irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would suggest avoiding php, just stick to JS/CSS/HTML

I'm not sure what's up, but adding CSS `style="padding-bottom: 32px"` might help.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:70%; padding-bottom:32px;">
```

---

A better solution is `display: flex;` on a parent, with `flex-direction: column`, and then put `flex: 0 0 auto` on the header and footer, then `flex: 1 0 auto` on the body so that it grows to fill parent's space. Maybe you need parent `position:relative; height: 100%;`

---

Also, you could try `box-sizing: border-box`. I would recommend to mess with it in the Chrome devtools Styles section